# Java - Edit Node's Elements depenting on node's attribute

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have this XML file:

```
<Credentials>
   <WebsiteApplication id="test">
      <Username>ADMIN</Username>
      <Password>ADMIN</Password>
   </WebsiteApplication>
</Credentials>
<Credentials>
   <WebsiteApplication id="test2">
      <Username>ADMIN2</Username>
      <Password>ADMIN2</Password>
   </WebsiteApplication>
</Credentials>
```

And i want to Edit the Username (or the password) of a "WebsiteApplication" node only if its id is the same with the one a gave a input..

i tried somethings that but it's not working...

```
 System.out.println("Insert the id:....");
    BufferedReader websiteIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String Editid = websiteIn.readLine().toString();


    Document doc = SecondaryFuncts.FindXML();

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList rootlist = root.getChildNodes();
    for(int i=0; i<rootlist.getLength(); i++) 
    {


//THERE IS NO PROBLEM UNTILL NOW... 
//And now i trying to take the id and check if matches
//with my input and them change nodes elements...

        Element Applications = (Element)rootlist.item(i);
        NamedNodeMap id = Applications.getAttributes();
        for(int ids = 0 ; ids <id.getLength(); ids++)
        {


I tried a lot in this loop but nothing worked.. what can i do here? 
Lets assume that i want username and password to change both as "test"

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath for such a task. You will select directly the correct `WebsiteApplication` element, and then you can modify its `Username` and `Password` children.

Select the correct element with the following XPath `/Credentials/WebsiteApplication[@id="XXX"]` where `XXX` is the input provided by the user.

Then just retrieve the children of that element and change the username/password content.

```
String inputId = "test1";
String xpathStr = "//Credentials/WebsiteApplication[@id='" + inputId + "']";
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr);
Node node = (Node)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
// node is the correct <WebsiteApplication> element
// do what you have to do with its children using node.getChildNodes()

// or you can even access directly the two elements
expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr + "/Username");
Node username = (Node)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
// and set their values using the setTextContent() method
username.setTextContent("test-username");

expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr + "/Password");
Node password = (Node)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
password.setTextContent("test-password");
```

See this complete sample:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class SO12477695 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<root>\r\n" + //
                "<Credentials>\r\n" + //
                "   <WebsiteApplication id=\"test\">\r\n" + //
                "      <Username>ADMIN</Username>\r\n" + //
                "      <Password>ADMIN</Password>\r\n" + //
                "   </WebsiteApplication>\r\n" + //
                "</Credentials>\r\n" + //
                "<Credentials>\r\n" + //
                "   <WebsiteApplication id=\"test2\">\r\n" + //
                "      <Username>ADMIN2</Username>\r\n" + //
                "      <Password>ADMIN2</Password>\r\n" + //
                "   </WebsiteApplication>\r\n" + //
                "</Credentials>\r\n" + //
                "</root>")));
        String inputId = "test2";
        String xpathStr = "//Credentials/WebsiteApplication[@id='" + inputId + "']";
        // retrieve elements and change their content
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr + "/Username");
        Node username = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        username.setTextContent("test-username");
        expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr + "/Password");
        Node password = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        password.setTextContent("test-password");
        // output the document
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
        System.out.println(writer.toString());

        // the document is now saved, you may want to save it in a file.
    }
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
   <Credentials>
      <WebsiteApplication id="test">
         <Username>ADMIN</Username>
         <Password>ADMIN</Password>
      </WebsiteApplication>
   </Credentials>
   <Credentials>
      <WebsiteApplication id="test2">
         <Username>test-username</Username>
         <Password>test-password</Password>
      </WebsiteApplication>
   </Credentials>
</root>
```

Comment: for some reason it is not working.. i dont get any errors so maybe the xpath expression ro find the node with the specific id is not working as i want.. what can be wrong..?